Why was the question on whether using a starlink in a plane is safe closed as off-topic?
Why was Does using a Starlink mini in a plane as a passenger pose a greater threat to the plane than using a smartphone connected to a cellular network? closed as off-topic by a mod? I thought it was about Aviation Safety, which is on-topic according to https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

There's really two parts to this, and even if we ignore the first (or reword to avoid it) then the second just gives us a different close reason. I was torn between "off topic" and "needs detail or clarity" when I cast my close vote.

As you can see from the link you posted about on-topic it specifically calls out that "passenger aspect of air travel" is off topic. Your question asks about safety as a passenger right there in the title. If you were asking about the effect on aviation safety from a regulatory, or flight safety, aspect then maybe this might be on topic.

Your title hints at a false assumption, that cellular phones still provide some flight safety problem. They may have in the past, but is that still strictly true today? It's worth reading the Q/A linked in the comments of your question. Why does the safety of cellular phones have anything to do with satellite communication? They are different technologies.


As is always the case, it is worth refining your question and hopefully getting some reopen votes. I'm also willing to accept I might have overstepped by using a mod hammer here as the second close vote (I usually wait for 2 close votes so I'm just the third). Lets see what the community thinks, and I'm happy to revert if needed.

Thanks, I edited the question. I believe the edit fixes 1 and 2. Is the question ok now?

I think so @FranckDernoncourt and it has 2 reopen votes so ill be the 3rd.
